# Asp.net core 2.0 Conditional DI

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

I have an interface that has 2 implementation
IMYService
MyServiceA
MYServiceB

Here the Implementation is dependent on some data in the request header used by the construtor of the Services like
If Header has value of internalId then use MyServiceA and pass that Id to the services in constructor
while if the value is missing use MyServiceB where as this service construct does not expect id.

My Controller is defined with DI for IMyservice

Answer (score 1):

In general, you need a factory. That's generally a separate class that is responsible to managing instances of a particular similar type of thing and returns the appropriate instance based on some sort of convention or condition. For example, if you've used `IHttpClientFactory`, you've see one in action.

Since the implementation depends on the request, you can cheat a little by using the "factory" overload of `AddScoped`:

```
services.AddScoped<IMyService>(p => 
{
    // return either MyServiceA or MyServiceB
});
```

The `p` param of the lambda is actually a scoped instance of `IServiceProvider`, so you can do stuff like pull out `IHttpContextAccessor` to look at the request details.